# Winrm error: The HTTP error (12152) is: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response. For Dell iDRAC calls

Tags: winrm

I am invoking Ws-Management calls to interact with iDRAC on Dell Server R620. 
Since, I am using windows machine, I am invoking windows WinRM commands for this purpose.

Command:
winrm e http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/root/dcim/DCIM_PhysicalDiskView   -u:[username] -p:[password]  -r:https:// [drac IP]/wsman -SkipCNCheck -SkipCACheck  -encoding:utf-8 -a:basic

So I intermittently receive following errorred response as:

---

```
Message = WS-Management cannot process the request. The operation failed because of an HTTP error. The HTTP error (12152) is: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response .
```

Error number:  -2147023901 0x800703E3
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

---

I have checked wireshark to monitor network and see consistent Frame Check Sequence Incorrect error, but this is intermittent

Has someone experienced something similar.

I have attempted to:
1. Disable Firewall on machine
2. Try multiple machines for same command

Comment: ever got it working?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work by disabling the request filtering capabilities of the antivirus.
Avast, for instance has something called HTTPS Scanning for the webShield. Also, the QUIC scanner does almost the same thing.

In the end, I found this topic which solved my issue with Avast on the target system:
https://mikefrobbins.com/2012/06/21/welcome-to-powershell-hell/